# Put application in foreground when app is in sleep mode using swift2

Tags: ios

I am doing some kind of app which runs 24 hours a day but at night time i want to put my ipad in sleep mode to save battery and in morning again i want my app in active mode automatically (Without user interaction).

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this, without jailbreaking.  There may also be no way even with jailbreaking.